# basic java rng guessing game

Tags: java

I want to make a random number guessing game but I keep getting thrown this error:

> "java: cannot find symbol
> symbol:   variable randNum
> location:
> class Main".

How can I resolve this?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        makeRandNum();
        readInput();
        checkInput();
    }

    public static void makeRandNum() {
        // creating number generator
        Random randNumGen = new Random();
        // generates the number
        int randNum = randNumGen.nextInt(11);
        System.out.println(randNum);
    }

    public static void readInput() {
        //creates a new instance of the util scanner class
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        // reads user input (int)
        int guessedNum = userInput.nextInt();

    }

    public static void checkInput(){
        if (guessedNum.equals(randNum)) {
            System.out.println("Correct");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **randNum** and **guessedNum** in **checkInput()** function but the variables are declared in **makeRandNum()** and **readInput()** function. To make the values accessible, make the return type of **makeRandNum()** and **readInput()**  as int and then pass the returned value to the **checkInput** function as parameter.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int randNum = makeRandNum();
        int guessedNum = readInput();
        checkInput(randNum, guessedNum);
    }
    public static int makeRandNum() {
        // creating number generator
        Random randNumGen = new Random();
        // generates the number
        int randNum = randNumGen.nextInt(11);
        System.out.println(randNum);
        return randNum;
    }
    public static int readInput() {
        // creates a new instance of the util scanner class
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        // reads user input (int)
        int guessedNum = userInput.nextInt();
        return guessedNum;
    }
    public static void checkInput(int randNum, int guessedNum) {
        if (guessedNum == randNum) {
            System.out.println("Correct");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect");
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is as follows :

```
5
15
Incorrect
```